# Rooting managed value in Rust

Tags: lifetime, rust

I'm trying to convert a `str` into a `Reader` and failing hard.

What below code does is extract Reader from `str` using with_str_reader

```
use std::io::{with_str_reader,Reader};

pub struct ReadSource<'self> {
    priv source: &'self Reader
}

impl<'self> ReadSource<'self> {

    fn from_str(data: &'self str) -> ReadSource<'self>{
        let r = std::io::with_str_reader(data, |reader| { reader });
        ReadSource{
            source : r
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
//Ignore        
}
```

What I get when running is the following

```
test.rs:12:21: 12:22 error: cannot root managed value long enough
test.rs:12             source : r

                                ^
test.rs:9:54: 14:5 note: managed value would have to be rooted for the lifetime &'self  as defined on the block at 9:54...
test.rs:9     fn from_str(data: &'self str) -> ReadSource<'self>{

test.rs:10         let r = std::io::with_str_reader(data, |reader| { reader });

test.rs:11         ReadSource{

test.rs:12             source : r

test.rs:13         }

test.rs:14     }
```

I know I have to cast something, with self lifetime but I'm unsure what?!

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at https://github.com/mozilla/rust/issues/5723 (and also at the source of `std::io::with_str_reader`).

Basically, `with_str_reader` is fundamentally unsound at present, and what you're doing is tripping it up badly, because letting the value escape from the closure like that isn't supposed to be permitted—the `with_foo` pattern means you can use that inside and inside only.

Comment: @DanielFath: I don't know; I haven't worked with it and don't have time to figure it out now. In the current master branch you'd be using the new runtime stuff which is somewhat different anyway.

Comment: When did those change land? I ask, because I compiled from source approximately two weeks ago. Are there any examples of the new runtime?

Comment: File I/O landed approximately two weeks ago. I haven't used it yet. It's in `std::rt::io::file`.